# unable to delete records from DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to delete all records from a table which is older than 10 minutes and keep only those which are 10 mins away from the current time. I tried using the following query statements but keep getting errors. exire_time Here is how it shows in DB Browser for SQLite

```
"2016-07-25 04:47:05.452000"
"2016-07-25 04:51:44.892000"
"2016-07-25 04:47:31.052000"
"2016-07-25 04:40:13.068000"
"2016-07-25 04:54:56.284000"
```

Please help.

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE expire_time < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 600);
```

**Error:** no such function: UNIX_TIMESTAMP:

```
DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE `expire_time` < ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -10 MINUTE);
```

**Error:** near "MINUTE": syntax error:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE expire_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

**Error:** near "10": syntax error:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE expire_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);
```

**Error:** near "15": syntax error:

Comment: You are using MySQL functions, but your database is SQLite.  Start with the documentation to learn the database you have chosen to use:  https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I went to through the page and found that my example looks like a `datetime(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)` which gives a time string like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS` i read it thrice but it does not give me an indea on how to delete the unwanted rows, the ones which are older than 10 mins. Appreciate if you can help me with the query syntax. Thanks

Comment: `delete FROM mytable WHERE datetime(expire_time) < datetime('now', '-600 seconds');` This worked for me but not sure if this is the correct and efficient way of doing it. Please advice